# Using with-redefs inside a doseq

Tags: clojure, mocking

I have a Ring handler which uses several functions to build the response. If any of these functions throw an exception, it should be caught so a custom response body can be written before returning a 500.

I'm writing the unit test for the handler, and I want to ensure that an exception thrown by any of these functions will be handled as described above. My instinct was to use `with-redefs` inside a `doseq`:

```
(doseq [f [ns1/fn1 ns1/fn2 ns2/fn1]]
  (with-redefs [f (fn [& args] (throw (RuntimeException. "fail!"))]
    (let [resp (app (request :get "/foo")))))]
      (is (= (:status resp) 500))
      (is (= (:body resp) "Something went wrong")))))
```

Of course, given that `with-redefs` wants to change the root bindings of vars, it is treating `f` as a symbol. Is there any way to get it to rebind the var referred to by `f`? I suspect that I'm going to need a macro to accomplish this, but I'm hoping that someone can come up with a clever solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with-redefs` is just sugar over repeated calls to `alter-var-root`, so you can just write the desugared form yourself, something like:

```
(doseq [v [#'ns1/fn1 #'ns1/fn2 #'ns2/fn1]]
  (let [old @v]
    (try
      (alter-var-root v (constantly (fn [& args]
                                      (throw (RuntimeException. "fail!")))))
      (let [resp (app (request :get "/foo")))
        (is (= (:status resp) 500))
        (is (= (:body resp) "Something went wrong")))
      (finally (alter-var-root v (constantly old))))))
```

Comment: I really should get into the habit of reading the Clojure source before asking these questions! Since most of Clojure is implemented in Clojure, it is actually possible to comprehend. Of course, having these questions and answers Googleable is basically the raison d'être for Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: @JoshGlover If you'd like to add an answer, please add one of your own instead of editing a bunch of stuff I never said into my answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought it fit well with your answer, given that it used your code. I wasn't really sure whether to add a new answer, add it as an update to my question, or what. Anyway, I'll add it as a new answer, if that is the most proper thing to do. Sorry again!

Answer (score 0):

Following on from [amalloy's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23779026/58994), here's a utility function that I wrote to use in my tests:

```
(defn with-mocks
  "Iterates through a list of functions to-mock, rebinding each to mock-fn, and calls
  test-fn with the optional test-args.

  Example:

      (defn foobar [a b]
        (try (+ (foo a) (bar b))
             (catch Exception _ 1)))

      (deftest test-foobar
        (testing \"Exceptions are handled\"

          (with-mocks
            [#'foo #'bar]
            (fn [& _] (throw (RuntimeException. \"\")))
            (fn [a b] (is (= 1 (foobar a b)))) 1 2)))"
  [to-mock mock-fn test-fn & test-args]
  (doseq [f to-mock]
    (let [real-fn @f]
      (try
        (alter-var-root f (constantly mock-fn))
        (apply test-fn test-args)
        (finally
          (alter-var-root f (constantly real-fn)))))))
```